# Rewrite %20 for a hyphen width one variable

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, space

I am strugling for a few hours with a code now..

I want to change spaces or %20 in a hyphen (-). I tried a lot but nothing will works.

This is my current code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sitecms/

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)$ page.php?page=$1
```

sitecms is my root, when $1 = test, I can go to localhost/sitecms/test. 
But when $1 = test test, I got localhost/sitecms/test%20test, and I need localhost/sitecms/test-test.

Can someone help me with a solution? I only needs to rewrite, not to redirect

Comment: If you type a URL containing a space into the address bar, then your browser does the job of properly encoding that as %20 for you. What problem are you actually trying to solve here, are you not in control of your own URLs? For any link or similar you have on your page, you decide what it links to in the first place - so why not make _that_ `test-test` to begin with, not some space-y nonsense?

Comment: I can control my urls, but the url is the same as the subject of a page. So I need to change a space to a hyphen

Comment: Then do that - at the time when you _create_ the URL. You're currently trying to fix this from the wrong end.

Comment: No, you dont understand. The URL is the same as a post. Exactly like this page, the subject is: Rewrite %20 for a hyphen width one variable and the url is: rewrite-20-for-a-hyphen-width-one-variable. I just need to rewrite spaces for a hyphen

Comment: Yes, exactly like this page - the URL _does_ contain hyphens instead of spaces already, there is no need to rewrite anything any more in regard to spaces. I'm getting the feeling that you don't really understand what the rewrite engine's job is. It is _not_ to fix the URLs that you put into you link `href` attributes to begin with. _Those_ should contain hyphens instead of spaces already - and therefor the replacing would be PHP's job in this situation.

Comment: There is a way to fix my problem, you can help me or telling me every time that I explain it wrong

Comment: I fixed this earlier with htaccess, but I dont remember how.

Comment: _"I fixed this earlier with htaccess, but I dont remember how."_ - good. Because if you did, you did it wrong. _"There is a way to fix my problem, you can help me"_ - I already tried to, by telling you that it is PHP's job to replace those spaces, at the time you create the URL to put into the `href` attribute of links, or wherever else you might be using such URLs.

Comment: `href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?><?php echo strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$page1["label"])); ?>`, I put this in my HREF,  it wil gives test-test, but the post URL is `test test` what changes to `test%20test`

Comment: _"but the post URL is test test"_ - you mean in your database? (So what would actually rather be called a "slug" in terms of most CMS.) Well then _change_ that!

Comment: Yes the slug.. Sorry for this mistake